# UIScrollView from interface builder (xcode 4.5) doesn't scroll

Tags: uiscrollview, interface-builder, ios6, xcode4.5

I set bounces vertically and horizontally to yes. Scroll enabled of course set to yes. I've checked all trivial ways to resolve this problem. I've also tried to create UIScrollView programmatically, but it doesn't work too on ios < 6.0. It doesn't work on simulators (5.0, 5.1) and device (5.1.1). In ios 6.0 simulator it works, but scrollers doesn't shows. Also UITableView has the same problem.

Elements, that i added from xcode 4.4 works fine. But all new elements i want to add give this problem. I've tried to create new project and check this behaviour and it's the same.

**UPD**:
there is one more problem. -touchesBegan:witEvent: doesn't respond if i tap on scrollView

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!make sure a scroll is needed; so you have more information (images, text, etc) in your scrollview than it can show you without scrolling. Feel free to show your code here :)

Comment: Thx! Earlier, in previous xcode versions scrollview works fine, even i haven't too many for one screen height content. It should bounces. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but "Bounce Verticaly" checkbox in IB works only with iOS 6 or later.

So you should do something like this in the code:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
```

Or:

```
[scrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set all necessary settings for the UIScrollView in code, when the View initiates.

Comment: I wrote that even if i create it programmatically i see this strange behaviour.

Comment: UIScrollView *sc = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollV.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:sc];
    [sc setBounces:YES];
    [sc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [sc setScrollEnabled:YES];
    UIView *rr = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 2000)];
    [sc addSubview:rr];
    [rr setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [rr release];
    [sc release];

Comment: Sorry for formatting i don't know how to format text right for now :(

Comment: You have very interesting row UIScrollView *sc = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollV.frame]; It seams you create duplicate of the scroll view with the same bounds like first. I mean you already have one scroll view and creating the second. In the case second view goes under first. You set up second view but look at first.

Comment: I know that :) the first was created in IB. and i tried to create another one in the code.

Comment: try [self.view bringSubviewToFront:sc]

Comment: Nope! it didn't help. Still inactive. But I found something interesting. I check contentSize and it show me {0, 0}. In iOS less than 6.0 scrollView doesn't scroll. And if even i set it to (0, 1) it start to scroll. But -touchesBegan:withEvent: still doesn't respond if i tap on scrollView.

Comment: I had the same issue last year, But with iOs 5.0. I could not fix it and  just set to (0;1) when view controller owner initializes.